# How do I suppress google tracking when blocking javascript is not enough?

Tags: javascript, tracking, privacy-protection, noscript, google-analytics

For this case I'm referring specifically to the website: http://www.golem.de/

I'm connecting to this website using Firefox with javascript disabled:
`about:config > javascript.enabled > no`

This should block scripts from "googlesyndication.com", which [NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/) lists as the only google script on the website to load, but there are still connections made to google servers which I detect using lsof:

`sudo lsof -i -P -r | grep 1e100`<sup>1</sup>

Blocking JS does not hinder Google from tracking me here (neither Ghostery or NoScript help). Why is this and how would I suppress Google tracking in this case?

__

1 - [about 1e100.net](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/174717?hl=en)

Comment: Chrome maintains several connections to Google servers for other purposes (updates, syncing, etc.). Are you sure the connection you are seeing is due to visiting that website?

Comment: @Dracs Yes, I am very confident. I'm not using Google search and automatic search engine updates are disabled. Everything prefetching related is disabled. Everything Google safebrowsing related is disabled as well. NoScript itself should not communicate with Google serves either. I really have no idea why these google connections still show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NoScript's main goal is to block **active** content to improve security.

If you block scripts from `google-analytics.com`, a request to connect to that domain can still be made if the data is not javascript. Another source for the observed connections can be (DNS-) prefetching.

In turn this means that blocking scripts using NoScript or Ghostery does not fully hinder advertising companies to track a user.

This is where **[Request Policy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/requestpolicy/)** comes in. It enables the user to define rules for cross-domain requests on a per domain basis. While this does give the user a higher degree of privacy control, it can be cumbersome to configure in addition with NoScript.

Comment: I wasn't able to get RequestPolicy to work.  The original has been abandoned, and the new one wasn't up to speed when I tried.  I also think RequestPolicy and NoScript have overlapping functionality and should be merged if possible.